# Minimum number of transactions to redistribute unequal shares

Tags: algorithms

I thought of a problem which must certainly be known:
n persons get an uneven share of m oranges, m being a multiple of n. All the persons having more than m/n oranges are to give their excess share to the less fortunate. What is the minimum number of transactions needed to reach a perfectly even distribution, each transaction being represented by a tuple i, j, k where i represents a source person, j represents a destination person, and k the number of oranges being transferred.

I think this problem can be represented as a DAG with the shortest path representing the solution. However, I am trying to find out if this is a classic problem.